# REST service over soap client

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, soap

I need to expose a REST service with data from a SOAP service. I am using jax-rs for the REST server and jax-ws for the SOAP client. I want to directly return the response from the SOAP service. My REST service gets the response from the SOAP service and returns it such as this:

```
 "ns3.Label": {
   "@xsi.nil": "true"
 }
```

I am using "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" as a provider. My problem is that I need an output like this:

```
"Label": null
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Dorin.

Comment: Are REST and SOAP endpoints on the same project?

Comment: No, they are in the different projects.